# Define specific field width for inline forms to fit all in one row

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have created a dynamic inline form with bootstrap 4 and javascript. I would like to fit all my fields in one row when viewed in a desktop/laptop browser. In the mobile view, I want to stack all my fields one below the other and they should be of equal width.

I tried the bootstrap grid column layout and also attempted to fix a width for each field but it does not seem to be working. Please help.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TEST PAGE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="TEST">
  <meta name="author" content="TEST">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico"> -->
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 </header>
  <!-- Begin page content -->
   <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container">
     <h3>EXAM SCHEDULE</h3><br>
      <form class="form-inline" id="fields" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div id="inside-container"></div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" name="status[]" value="" placeholder="Text message" maxlength="160">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
        <input type="file" id="media" name="media[]" value="" placeholder="Media" accept="image/*|video/*">
       </div>

       <div class="form-group p-2">

        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datesched" name="datesched[]" value="" placeholder="Scheduled Date" max="2100-12-31" min="2019-11-01">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2">
         <select class="form-control" id="recurrence" name="recurrence[]">
          <option value="0">Once</option>
          <option value="7">Weekly</option>
          <option value="30">Monthly</option>
          <option value="90">Quarterly</option>
          <option value="365">Yearly</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-group p-2">
         <select class="form-control" id="profile" name="profile[]">
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
         </select>
        </div>
       <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="fields();"><span>+</span></button>

       </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="dynamicform.js"></script>
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript code is provided below:

```
var room = 1;

function fields() {
 room++;

 var objTo = document.getElementById('inside-container')

 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
 var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
 divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group p-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" name="status[]" value="" placeholder="Text message" maxlength="160"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><input type="file" id="media" name="media[]" value="" placeholder="Media" accept="image/*|video/*"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><input type="date" class="form-control" id="datesched" name="datesched[]" value="" placeholder="Scheduled Date" max="2100-12-31" min="2019-11-01"></div><div class="form-group p-2"><select class="form-control" id="recurrence" name="recurrence[]"><option value="0">Once</option><option value="7">Weekly</option><option value="30">Monthly</option><option value="90">Quarterly</option><option value="365">Yearly</option></select></div><div class="input-group"><div class="form-group p-2"><select class="form-control" id="profile" name="profile[]"><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option></select></div><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_fields('+ room +');"><span>-</span></button></div><div class="clear"></div>';
 objTo.appendChild(divtest)

}

function remove_fields(rid) {
 $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
```

I am unable to fit all the fields in one row in desktop view. I want my inline form to be mobile-responsive as well. Please advise.

Comment: if my answer works please mark it as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The form is working as expected now. All fields are in one row. However, the middle 3 fields appear to be clubbed together. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See I have changed few things in your code . What I did was just added `col-sm` for div classes. You can find more about bootstrap grid system via this link.  [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) . Please go through the code because I have removed some codes from your original code. I think you expect this.***To see the result please expan the snippet and then with Inspect Element in you browser and then navigate to mobile view*** . Thanks

**Desktop view**

[image: Desktop view]

**Mobile view**

[image: Mobile view]

```js
   var room = 1;

function fields() {
 room++;
 var objTo = document.getElementById('inside-container')
 var divtest = document.createElement("div");
 divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
 var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
 divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" name="status[]" value="" placeholder="Text message" maxlength="160"></div><div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-2"><input type="file" id="media" name="media[]" value="" placeholder="Media" accept="image/*|video/*"></div><div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-2"><input type="date" class="form-control" id="datesched" name="datesched[]" value="" placeholder="Scheduled Date" max="2100-12-31" min="2019-11-01"></div><div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-2"><select class="form-control" id="recurrence" name="recurrence[]"><option value="0">Once</option><option value="7">Weekly</option><option value="30">Monthly</option><option value="90">Quarterly</option><option value="365">Yearly</option></select></div><div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-1"><select class="form-control" id="profile" name="profile[]"><option value="1">A</option><option value="2">B</option></select></div>  <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-1"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block" type="button" onclick="remove_fields('+ room +');"><span>-</span></button></div><div class="clear col-sm-1"></div>';
 objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
function remove_fields(rid) {
 $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TEST PAGE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="TEST">
  <meta name="author" content="TEST">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico"> -->
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
 </header>
  <!-- Begin page content -->
   <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container">
     <h3>EXAM SCHEDULE</h3><br>
      <form class="form-inline" id="fields" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div id="inside-container"></div>
       <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" name="status[]" value="" placeholder="Text message" maxlength="160">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-2">
        <input type="file" id="media" name="media[]" value="" placeholder="Media" accept="image/*|video/*">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datesched" name="datesched[]" value="" placeholder="Scheduled Date" max="2100-12-31" min="2019-11-01">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-2">
         <select class="form-control" id="recurrence" name="recurrence[]">
          <option value="0">Once</option>
          <option value="7">Weekly</option>
          <option value="30">Monthly</option>
          <option value="90">Quarterly</option>
          <option value="365">Yearly</option>
         </select>
       </div>
        <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-1">
         <select class="form-control" id="profile" name="profile[]">
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
         </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group p-2 col-sm-1">
       <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="button" onclick="fields();"><span>+</span></button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="dynamicform.js"></script>
   </main> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be good if we could equally space out all the fields. Right now, the fields appear clubbed together in the middle although they are in 1 row. Don't know why. :-/